# getting div content and displaying it as the last "li" not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the contents of a `div` and display them as the last `li` on a `ul` for a mobile menu. The markup for the content is generated with php so I can't simply append html.

I have tried using `sethtml` and `append` without success.

This is my attempt:

```
$("#mobile-menu li").last().append($("#header-top-widget-area-2 div").innerHTML);
```

Here is the markup generated with php that I need to display as the last `li` in mobile menu:

```
<div class="ewf-span6 text-right" id="header-top-widget-area-2">
  <div id="text-3" class="widget widget_text">
    <h3 class="widget-title"><span> </span></h3>
    <div class="textwidget">
      <ul class="social-icons">
        <li class="facebook"><a href="#"><img class="social-icon" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/fb_responsive.png" alt="facebook-icon"></a></li>
        <li class="linkedin"><a href="#"><img class="social-icon" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/linkedin_responsive.png" alt="linkedin-icon"></a></li>
        <li class="twitter"><a href="#"><img class="social-icon" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/twitter_responsive.png" alt="twitter-icon"></a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="green-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li class="border"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the content of the div is the `ul`, do you really wanna show that?

Comment: Where's the element with the ID mobile-menu?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new `<li>` element, populate it with your content, and append it to your `<ul>` element:

```
var newLi = $("<li />");
newLi.html($("#header-top-widget-area-2 div")[0].innerHTML);
$("#mobile-menu").append(newLi);
```

Comment: Your soulution makes sense but it isn't working. when I alert newLi I get object Object.